Why does one laptop require closer proximity to printer than another?
We have a Samsung 2830x wireless printer downstairs and two laptop computers upstairs that connect to it wirelessly. The laptops show similar upload and download speeds on speed tests, but one laptop will print successfully from its upstairs location while the other has to be carried physically down the stairs toward the printer, within a few feet, before it will connect. What might cause this?

If you're connecting using the "WiFi Direct" mode then the range and other specific factors of the hardware will influence performance. But perhaps you shouldn't be using that mode and instead connect the printer to your network like any other device? Doing so, as long as the laptops are connected to the same router there mustn't  be any difference.

The most likely cause is simple: the wireless radio and antenna design in the laptops differs, and this impacts how and where these laptops can reliably connect to the network broadcast by the printer.
The better way to set up a printer on a network is to connect the printer to the existing network in the house, wired or wireless. Different printers will implement this differently, and it may not be an option on some. But, if your printer can connect to an existing network, then all devices connected to that network will be able to "see" the printer so long as they are connected to the main network.

I guess I didn't explain it very well, but they are all connected to the same network. The router and the printer are downstairs in different rooms. Both laptops show similar download and upload speeds upstairs, but one won't print successfully until you take it within a few, say 10 or 15, feet of the printer. That's what has me puzzled.

Hey guys, thanks for your help--I think maybe I have it figured out based on what you guys were suggesting. I did have all three connected to my network, but after you guys mentioned having the laptop connected directly to the printer's network I went in and looked again at the configuration--I believe that somehow I had the wrong port checked on the laptop's printer connection and it was indeed connecting directly to the printer instead of going through the router. Changed that and it seems to be working. Thanks...

If you find the answer to be useful, consider to upvote with the up arrow button. If you feel that the answer was the solution for you, select that button as well.
